# Skipping a value in a range within a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, range

So the course I'm in posted an exercise:

```
# Modify the code inside this loop to stop when i is exactly divisible by 11
for i in range(0, 100, 7):
    print(i)
```

I added:

```
if i % 11 == 0:
        break
```

However my code gets stuck on the first value as it is 0 thus ending the program.
What function would I use to skip over the first value and proceed with the rest of the range?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not replace `range(0, 100, 7)` with `range(7, 100, 7)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "skip over" a certain value (here 0), you can use python's `continue`

```
for i in range(0, 100, 7):
    print(i)
    if i == 0:
        continue
    if i % 11 == 0:
        break
```

This is like a break statement, but it returns you to the top of the loop instead of skipping to the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do as below:

```
print(0)
for i in range(1, 100, 7):
    print(i)
    if i % 11 == 0:
        break
```

Print the first value and start the loop from index 1.